# Can't enter my password when trying to create a Laravel project with Sail on Windows

Tags: laravel-8, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I want to create a new Laravel 8 project and I followed the documentation with docker and Sail on Windows: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-windows

After I installed everything, I tried executing the command to create the project:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

It asked me for my password. I entered it and pressed enter, but nothing happened. When I press CTRL+C, I can see that it tried to execute my password as a command.

Comment: have you tried doing it the other way around? using sudo su first, entering your password, and then using the curl command?

Comment: That seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Now I get an error though. "chown: cannot access '.': No such file or directory"

Comment: Oh well, thats weird af, as . is the current directory...

Comment: I know. It also didn't create the project

Comment: you did everything using root/sudo , right? And what directory are you in?

Comment: Yes. I just realized, there are other errors as well... "Cannot create project directory at "/opt/example-app", it exists as a file." and "bash: line 16: cd: example-app: No such file or directory"

Comment: I think you are in a directory with restricted rights, go to your home and create a directory called projects, then go into that folder and repeat the command

Comment: Yep, that worked! I was just in D:\projects, but putting it in C:\projects worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should create a folder called projects inside your home directory, then, go into that folder and execute `sudo curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

You could also do `sudo su` and then `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

Answer (score 4):

run it in WSL command line, not in windows command prompt.

it must work

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows Terminal. Open it with your Linux distribution. And try again.

[image]